# How to write cross staff beams in Noteflight?

Tags: piano, beaming, noteflight

In the middle section of Symphony No 5 by Beethoven, I see some cross staff beams (marked in red):

[image: Excerpt of Beethoven's Symphony No 5 with some cross staff beams circled]

Can you please tell me how to write them in Noteflight?

Answer (score 4):

Noteflight doesn't offer cross-staff beaming. There are several [requests for this on their user support forum](https://support.noteflight.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360054838991-Allow-Cross-Staff-Beaming-Arpeggios-Slurs)

Comment: Why are the Noteflight developers not adding this feature now?

Comment: @Vighnesh Try asking *them*.

Comment: This is one of the reasons I tried to install the appropriate apps to create .ly and .mscz files respectively.

Comment: @Vighnesh You might have more luck with [Musescore](https://musescore.org/en)

Comment: Musescore is the source of both the images I had posted.

Comment: I would require an admin's password to install Musescore.

Comment: @Vighnesh Noteflight offers a lightweight in-browser option for simple notation tasks, but it isn’t a fully-featured engraving solution; it’s not meant to be. If you don’t have a machine on which you have the rights to install software, then maybe that’s the problem you need to solve first.

Comment: What about SIBELIUS?

Comment: @Vighnesh Sibelius of course does cross staff beaming, but if you don't have the permissions to install Musescore then you won't have the permissions to install Sibelius. Sibelius is an expensive commercial program, Musescore is free.

Comment: So should I check in SIBELIUS before installing Musescore?

Comment: @Vighnesh Musescore and Sibelius both do cross-staff beaming

Comment: @PiedPiper I am talking about permissions.

Comment: @Vighnesh Try [Soundslice](https://www.soundslice.com/), which is web-based (not requiring software installation) and [supports cross-staff beaming](https://www.soundslice.com/help/en/creating/notations/310/cross-staff-music/).

Comment: @AdrianHolovaty You sent me a link to a non-existent website?! When I click on the link to Soundslice, it says 'This site can't be reached. www.soundslice.com refused to connect'.

Comment: @Vighnesh The site does indeed work. I just tried it myself. Check your Internet connection?